# Keyboard is not displayed in iPhone 5

Tags: ios, keyboard, show

In iPhone 4, it's working.
But in iOhone 5, it's not working

Why is not working in iPhone 5, any idea??

In xib file I have selected user interaction enabled

```
-(void)hideKeyboard{
    [self.view resignFirstResponder];
}
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing: (UITextField *)textField

{
    UIToolbar * keyboardToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];

    keyboardToolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
    [keyboardToolBar setItems: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"First" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(previousTextField)],

                                [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Last" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(nextTextField)],
                                [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                                [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Close" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(resignKeyboard)],
                                nil]];
    textField.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolBar;

}

- (void)nextTextField {
     [self hideKeyboard ];
     UITextField * txtTeamName = (UITextField *)sender;
     [txtTeamName becomeFirstResponder];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing: (UITextField *)textField
```

This methods expect a `BOOL` return. Add `return YES;` at the end of this method.